# moodle gets into 'endless redirection' when configured as subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect, moodle

I'd like to setup my moodle instance to be available by address: http://mymoodle.mysite.com.

mysite.com is already registered and I can easily access it because I've configured it at my hosting provider to refer to the IP (let's say IP address `x.x.x.x`) of my server where I store my web page.
To register the subdomain I'm specifying another IP address where my moodle instance is installed (e.g. `y.y.y.y`) and configure my provider to do permanent redirect to the URL http://y.y.y.y

moodle instance is installed at wwwroot folder of the web sever, it's accessible via http://y.y.y.y

Now it works for me in the following way: I type http://mymoodle.mysite.com in address bar of my browser and it redirects me to my moodle instance, I see a main screen, all works fine but the URL in address bar is changed to http://y.y.y.y

Alhtough I'd like to see my fancy subdomain address but not IP.

My config.php originally looks like that
`$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://y.y.y.y';`

but if I change it to
`$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://mymoodle.mysite.com';`
I'm getting into 'endless redirects'.
Is there a way to resolve this issue and get rid of IP address in address bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the url of Moodle after the set-up you have to follow those steps : https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Moodle_migration. Only updating $CFG->wwwroot will not be ok.

Comment: migration was done accordingly those instructions

Comment: The access from http://mymoodle.mysite.com to your IP is done with an A or AAAA DNS record or with a 301 redirect ? If you have a 301 redirect, you will still see the target address.

Comment: You need to do it with an A Record (IPV4) or AAAA Record (IPV6)

Comment: hm, could be a good idea, need to check it with my host provider

Comment: unfortunately didn't work, but the fresh installation of moodle helped